# Use a where query multiple times on same model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query on Laravel that I want my user to be able to filter homes by type.  My problem is that I want to use this more than one time in my query.

For example in 10 check boxes from 1 to 10 there are 10 different type of homes that user may click only one type to filter, or all 10.  I want to return all homes to my user.

If I have to use `orwhere` it would be like 10 `orwhere` in my query clause. I want to know if this is the best way to do this:

```
  $type_id = $request->get('type_id');
  $somefiled= $request->get('somefiled');

        $data = home::with('city')
            ->where('type_id',$type_id)->get()
            ->orWhere('somefiled',$somefiled)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user sends more than one type of home, bring this in as an array from the form data and use `whereIn` for your query:

```
$data = home::with('city')
        ->whereIn('type_id', $type_id)->get();
```

This will work for one or many choices of types.  When you create your array for types, you may wish to rename the variable to something plural to prevent confusion (like `$types` or `$type_ids`).

EDIT

as whereIn Act as Orwhere but just for arrays you can simply use it instead of orwhere for multiple quesries .

```
       $data = home::with('city')
        ->whereIn('type_id', $type_id)
->whereIn('otherfields', $otherfields')
->get();
```

Comment: how about when i want to use more that 2 filters now i use orWhere can i use some thing like Orwherein ??

Comment: Yes, you can use either of those.  However, I suggest you test with the changes in my answer - just get the basics of your original question working first.  It is not too hard using `whereIn`, but just test it - play with it - to make sure you have that working the way you want.  Then, try with the next bit of adding a different filter.  it will work, **yes**, but that's really a different question - get the original issue working first and understand how it works at the basic level - then add the complexity later :)

Comment: i think u got me a bit wrong my question was that do we have some thing like orWhere for arrays like Wherein ?? some thing like orWhereIn ?? then how would be the answer to my edited question if u have seen that

Comment: Yes, you can use either of those.  But, I was answering the original question first, as that is a pretty big change.  I suggest you get that working correctly first - then try to add another type of clause.  `whereIn` will do what you need for the **type**.  You don't need an OR at that point, because `whereIn` pulls in only those types that were selected in an array.  You can then add more queries as well like `orWhere('somefiled',$somefiled)` before you call `get()`, but I recommend you get the type `whereIn` working first, then try the next question of adding more filters.